# Slide Up Transition of React Component

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, css-animations, transition

I am just starting to use animations/transition in my `React.js` projects. In the GIF below, when I close a `Message` component, it fades out. After it fades, I hide the component using `onAnimationEnd`.

What I want to happen is when a `Message` disappears have the below Components slide up. I am unsure conceptually how I would accomplish this either via a CSS animation/transition or via a React specific way.

[image]

**Message.js**

```
import React, {PropTypes, Component} from 'react';
import MessageTypes from '../constants/MessageTypes';

export default class Message extends Component {

    constructor(props, context) {
        super(props, context);
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
        this.onAnimationEnd = this.onAnimationEnd.bind(this);
        this.state = {
            animate: false,
            hide: false
        }
    }

    handleClick(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        this.setState({animate: true});
    }

    onAnimationEnd() {
        console.log('fdsfd');
        this.setState({hide: true});
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div ref="message" onAnimationEnd={this.onAnimationEnd} className={`card message ${this.state.hide ? 'hide open' : ''} ${this.state.animate ? 'message-transition-fade-out' : ''}`}>
                <span className={`icon icon-${this.iconLevel()}`} style={{color: `#${this.iconColor()}`}}></span>
                <p>
                    <strong>{this.props.title}</strong><br />
                    <span dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: this.props.message }} />
                </p>
                <a href="#" onClick={this.handleClick}>
                    <span className="icon icon-close"></span>
                </a>
            </div>  
        );
    }

}
```

**Message.scss**

```
.message {

    max-height: 150px;
    transition: height 2s ease;

    &.open {
        height: 0; //define your height or use max-height
    }

    &-transition {

        &-fade-out {

            @include animation(0s, .3s, fadeout);

        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an `npm` module called `react-collapse` that does the trick.

```
<Collapse isOpened={this.state.isOpened} keepCollapsedContent={true}>
     //content here
</Collapse>
```

Here are the results:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest you to use `css transitions`.

Have a class called `open` attached to the root of the `Message` component. `onAnimationEnd` remove the class `open`. Now, use `height` to animate that class.

Pseudo code.

```
.message {
 height: 0px;
 transition: height 0.3s ease;
}

.message.open {
  height: 100px; //define your height or use max-height  
}
```

Comment: doesn't seem to be working. I added the relevant code with your suggestions to my question.

Comment: Don't need for animation. Just follow the Pseudo code.

Comment: The animation is for the previous Message fadeout. In `onAnimationEnd` i'm adding the `open` class. Doesn't seem to be working. Fixed the CSS.

Comment: actually you suggest removing the open class and I am adding it. Let me fix that.

Comment: Have the class `open` always and remove it on `onAnimationEnd` and use the css I gave in the Pseudo code.